# str_replace include return 1

Tags: php, arrays, include, str-replace

```
$markup_array = array();
    $name_array = array();
    while($array = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name_array = $array['plugin_name'];
    $markup = '{$'.$array['plugin_name'].'}';
    }
$callback = str_replace($markup, include("plugins/".$name_array."/".$name_array.".php"), $buffer);
```

here is the complete code

```
function callback($buffer)
{
GLOBAL $mysqli;
GLOBAL $db_prefix;
GLOBAL $parameters;

$query = $mysqli->query("...query...");
$count = $query->num_rows;
    if($count > 0) {
    $markup_array = array();
    $name_array = array();
    while($array = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name_array = $array['plugin_name'];
    $markup = '{$'.$array['plugin_name'].'}';
    }
$callback = str_replace($markup, include('plugins/'.$name_array.'/'.$name_array.'.php'), $buffer);
  }

  return $callback;
}

function load_theme() {
GLOBAL $mysqli;
GLOBAL $db_prefix;
GLOBAL $parameters;
$query = $mysqli->query("...query...");
$count = $query->num_rows;
    if($count > 0) {
    $theme_parameters = array();
    $array = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $theme_parameters['ID_THEME'] = $array['ID_THEME'];
    $theme_parameters['theme_name'] = $array['theme_name'];
    $theme_parameters['theme_version'] = $array['theme_version'];
    $theme_parameters['theme_folder'] = 'themes/'.$array['theme_folder'].'/';
    $theme_parameters['theme_status'] = $array['theme_status'];

//loading pages
ob_start("callback");
require_once($theme_parameters['theme_folder'].'/header.php');
require_once($theme_parameters['theme_folder'].'/body.php');
require_once($theme_parameters['theme_folder'].'/footer.php');
ob_end_flush();
```

File I want to include:

```
<ul id="horizontalmenu">
<li class="parent">Home</li>
<? 
$query_pages = $mysqli->query("...query...");
while($pages_array = $query_pages->fetch_assoc()) 
    { 
echo '<li class="parent"><a href="'.$pages_array['ID_PAGE'].'_'.text2url($pages_array['title']).'.html">'.$pages_array['title'].'</a>';
list_pages_home_child($id_parent);
echo '</li>';
    }
    ?>
<li class="parent">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

And so, the include return 1. Any clue about how to return the file content of the include and not just "1"?
In the php file I want to include, there is $var and functions, so file_get_contents() is not enough. I get `Fatal error: Unknown: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: How to not get just 1... With common sense, nobody wants "1" with an include

Comment: Read the [documentation for `include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) : `Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1.`.

Comment: I checked it already, problem is I don't know how to overridden...?

Comment: @Dorian_gd: The problem is that you're using the wrong function here. `include()` includes **AND** evaluates the specified file. You just need `file_get_contents()` here.

Comment: In $name_array.php I have php, file_get_contents() return only html

Comment: please add what you have in the included file and how you want to further use the contents of it. "var and functions" is not enough as to understand what they are supposed to do

Comment: I just add the content of the file I want to include. Maybe I should try to find an other way to load the content.

Comment: also include the explenation part - as the way you use your code right now is wrong in so many ways its difficult to understand the intention behind what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Taking away from this [include example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-144) in the docs you need to have a `return` statement in your `$name_array . "/" . $name_array . ".php"` file to get any contents back from including a file.

return.php

```
<?php
    $var = 'PHP';
    return $var;
?>
```

noreturn.php

```
<?php
    $var = 'PHP';
?>
```

testreturns.php

```
<?php
    $foo = include 'return.php';
    echo $foo; // prints 'PHP'
    
    $bar = include 'noreturn.php';
    echo $bar; // prints 1
?>
```

If you want the actual PHP code from your file you should use [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents).

Comment: well, it solve half of the problem. This way looks like to not working with functions

Comment: Thank you for your help. This way, `I get Fatal error: Unknown: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in Unknown on line 0`